# sql group by sum of all sums

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a query (formatted for Oracle):

```
select sum(inv.quantity * inv.price), spn.salesperson_name
from invoice inv
inner join salesperson spn on spn.spn_id = inv.spn_id
where inc.invoice_date between to_date('05/01/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') and to_date('05/31/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') 
group by spn.salesperson_name
```

To add up invoices for the month of May. The result is similar to:

```
$446,088.62     Bob
$443,439.29     Sally
$275,097.00     Tom
 $95,170.00     George
 $53,150.00     Jill
```

But, I need to divide each sum to the sum of the sums ($1,312,944.91), so that the result is:

```
$446,088.62     34%  Bob
$443,439.29     34%  Sally
$275,097.00     21%  Tom
 $95,170.00      7%  George
 $53,150.00      4%  Jill
```

(The sum of the percentage column should be 100%)

Is there a way to accomplish this in the query?

Comment: You may also want to consider `ratio_to_report()` - I posted a solution using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When functions exist that do **exactly** what you need, it is best to use those functions. In this case, the SQL Standard analytic function `RATIO_TO_REPORT` (which is implemented at least in Oracle and SQL Server) does exactly what you need. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions124.htm

Specifically, the `select` clause could be:

```
select sum(inv.quantity * inv.price) AS TOTAL_REVENUE   --  use column aliases!
     , ratio_to_report(sum(inv.quantity * inv.price)) over () AS RATIO,
     , spn.salesperson_name
from   .......   (rest of your query goes here)
```

Note that this solution, like the Accepted Answer, will show the ratio as a decimal, not as a percentage (and not rounded). If you need to attach a percentage sign, you will need to convert to string... and if so, the following trick (it is a trick!) will give you what you need:

```
to_char( ratio_to_report(.....), 'fm99L', 'nls_currency = %' ) AS RATIO, .....
```

The `L` element in `to_char` is for currency symbol; you define the currency symbol to be the percent sign.

Comment: I agree. This is a better answer because the function is exact and makes the code more concise.

Answer (score 2):

Just use analytic functions:

```
select spn.salesperson_name, sum(inv.quantity * inv.price), 
       sum(inv.quantity * inv.price)  / sum(sum(inv.quantity * inv.price)) over () as ratio 
from invoice inv inner join
     salesperson spn
     on spn.spn_id = inv.spn_id
where inc.invoice_date between date '2017-05-01' and date '2017-05-31'
group by spn.salesperson_name;
```