# Group by and sum of all of groups in Athena/Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Is there a way to get `SUM` of all groups along with `group  by`?

For example, if I were to borrow the query from another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44420300/sql-group-by-sum-of-all-sums)

```
select sum(inv.quantity * inv.price), spn.salesperson_name
from invoice inv
inner join salesperson spn on spn.spn_id = inv.spn_id
where inc.invoice_date between to_date('05/01/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') and to_date('05/31/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') 
group by spn.salesperson_name
```

Which gives result as shown below,

```
$446,088.62     Bob
$443,439.29     Sally
$275,097.00     Tom
 $95,170.00     George
 $53,150.00     Jill
```

But I want to show the Total Sales as well, along with the individual sales,

```
     $446,088.62     Bob
     $443,439.29     Sally
     $275,097.00     Tom
      $95,170.00     George
      $53,150.00     Jill
   $1,037,847.91     Total Sales <= SUM of all groups
```

Currently I am duplicating the query without the `group by` and doing a `UNION ALL` with the individual result, which is nasty and has the worst performance.

In the linked SO question (even though it is `Oracle` and calculating the percentage of sales), is there something similar analytic functions in Athena/Presto that we can use to create the `Total Sales` row?

Comment: Does athena support rollup? `group by spn.salesperson_name with ROLLUP`

Answer (score 2):

If name not required try this:

```
select sum(inv.quantity * inv.price), spn.salesperson_name
from invoice inv
inner join salesperson spn on spn.spn_id = inv.spn_id
where inc.invoice_date between to_date('05/01/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') and to_date('05/31/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') 
group by ROLLUP(spn.salesperson_name)
```

Output will be like this:

```
 $446,088.62    Bob
 $443,439.29    Sally
 $275,097.00    Tom
 $95,170.00     George
 $53,150.00     Jill
 $1,037,847.91  null (total)
```

I can also suggest putting the query in a WITH:

```
with info AS (
select sum(inv.quantity * inv.price) as summ, spn.salesperson_name
from invoice inv
inner join salesperson spn on spn.spn_id = inv.spn_id
where inc.invoice_date between to_date('05/01/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') and to_date('05/31/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') 
group by spn.salesperson_name
)
select * from info
UNION ALL
SELECT sum(summ) as summ, 'Total Sales' as salesperson_name from info
```

Output:

```
 $446,088.62    Bob
 $443,439.29    Sally
 $275,097.00    Tom
 $95,170.00     George
 $53,150.00     Jill
 $1,037,847.91  Total Sales
```

Answer (score 1):

To build upon [Ksu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73856657/10871073) to get the name of the column, using the coalesce function might work to give the column name as well:

```
select sum(inv.quantity * inv.price), COALESCE(spn.salesperson_name, "Total Sales") as salesperson_name
from invoice inv
inner join salesperson spn on spn.spn_id = inv.spn_id
where inc.invoice_date between to_date('05/01/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') and to_date('05/31/2017', 'MM/dd/YYYY') 
group by ROLLUP(salesperson_name)
```